# how do i clean up the output of a bash script outputting a command

Tags: bash

So i have this script. it outputs temp data for a server. When you run it normally not in a bash script it looks something like this

```
#!/bin/bash

echo $(sensors -f)

sleep 20

done
```

---

it outputs temp data for a server. When you run it normally not in a bash script it looks something like this

---

```
i5k_amb-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Ch. 0 DIMM 0: +145.4°F  (low  = +221.0°F, high = +255.2°F)

Ch. 0 DIMM 1: +141.8°F  (low  = +221.0°F, high = +248.0°F)

Ch. 1 DIMM 0: +141.8°F  (low  = +221.0°F, high = +255.2°F)

Ch. 1 DIMM 1: +133.7°F  (low  = +221.0°F, high = +255.2°F)

Ch. 2 DIMM 0: +158.9°F  (low  = +221.0°F, high = +255.2°F)

Ch. 2 DIMM 1: +134.6°F  (low  = +221.0°F, high = +255.2°F)

Ch. 3 DIMM 0: +131.9°F  (low  = +221.0°F, high = +248.0°F)

Ch. 3 DIMM 1: +148.1°F  (low  = +221.0°F, high = +255.2°F)

coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Core 0:      +123.8°F  (high = +179.6°F, crit = +212.0°F)

Core 1:      +114.8°F  (high = +179.6°F, crit = +212.0°F)

Core 2:      +120.2°F  (high = +179.6°F, crit = +212.0°F)

Core 3:      +118.4°F  (high = +179.6°F, crit = +212.0°F)

coretemp-isa-0001
Adapter: ISA adapter
Core 0:      +127.4°F  (high = +179.6°F, crit = +212.0°F)

Core 1:      +118.4°F  (high = +179.6°F, crit = +212.0°F)

Core 2:      +118.4°F  (high = +179.6°F, crit = +212.0°F)

Core 3:      +118.4°F  (high = +179.6°F, crit = +212.0°F)
```

---

So this looks fine. Except when you run it WITH the script you get this.

---

```
i5k_amb-isa-0000 Adapter: ISA adapter Ch. 0 DIMM 0: temp1_input: 63.000 temp1_max: 124.000 temp1_min: 105.000 temp1_alarm: 0.000 Ch. 0 DIMM 1: temp2_input: 60.500 temp2_max: 120.000 temp2_min: 105.000 temp2_alarm: 0.000 Ch. 1 DIMM 0: temp3_input: 61.000 temp3_max: 124.000 temp3_min: 105.000 temp3_alarm: 0.000 Ch. 1 DIMM 1: temp4_input: 56.500 temp4_max: 124.000 temp4_min: 105.000 temp4_alarm: 0.000 Ch. 2 DIMM 0: temp5_input: 70.500 temp5_max: 124.000 temp5_min: 105.000 temp5_alarm: 0.000 Ch. 2 DIMM 1: temp6_input: 57.000 temp6_max: 124.000 temp6_min: 105.000 temp6_alarm: 0.000 Ch. 3 DIMM 0: temp7_input: 55.500 temp7_max: 120.000 temp7_min: 105.000 temp7_alarm: 0.000 Ch. 3 DIMM 1: temp8_input: 64.000 temp8_max: 124.000 temp8_min: 105.000 temp8_alarm: 0.000 coretemp-isa-0000 Adapter: ISA adapter Core 0: temp2_input: 50.000 temp2_max: 82.000 temp2_crit: 100.000 temp2_crit_alarm: 0.000 Core 1: temp3_input: 46.000 temp3_max: 82.000 temp3_crit: 100.000 temp3_crit_alarm: 0.000 Core 2: temp4_input: 49.000 temp4_max: 82.000 temp4_crit: 100.000 temp4_crit_alarm: 0.000 Core 3: temp5_input: 48.000 temp5_max: 82.000 temp5_crit: 100.000 temp5_crit_alarm: 0.000 coretemp-isa-0001 Adapter: ISA adapter Core 0: temp2_input: 54.000 temp2_max: 82.000 temp2_crit: 100.000 temp2_crit_alarm: 0.000 Core 1: temp3_input: 48.000 temp3_max: 82.000 temp3_crit: 100.000 temp3_crit_alarm: 0.000 Core 2: temp4_input: 48.000 temp4_max: 82.000 temp4_crit: 100.000 temp4_crit_alarm: 0.000 Core 3: temp5_input: 48.000 temp5_max: 82.000 temp5_crit: 100.000 temp5_crit_alarm: 0.000
```

---

Do you see where this looks unreadable compared to the first output? so how do i make the output of the data i get when it's run in the script looking like the data i get when i just run the standalone command.

---

Comment: there is not loop in your code that would justify the behaviour or the done statement....

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind i just used watch sensors -f that works great for what im doing.